# Should I use constexpr like this?

Tags: c++, c++11, constexpr

I have this pretty simple function, I have some values that need to be calculated but only once and the best time would be at compile time.  These values only matter within this function.  Is this a good use of constexpr or should I just declare them static const?

ps I know that the performance difference is so little to not matter, but I want to do it the "Right" c++11 way.

```
void MainWindow::UpdateDateTimes()
{
// for some dumb reason DateTime only has add seconds method
    // so we have to calculate the seconds per hour and the number of hours
    // we do this with static constant values so that the calculations
    // only happen once.
    static constexpr const int secsPerHour = 60 * 60;
    static constexpr const int cdtOffsetHours = -5;
    static constexpr const int edtOffsetHours = -4;
    static constexpr const int cetOffsetHours = 2;
    static constexpr const int cdtOffsetSecs = secsPerHour * cdtOffsetHours;
    static constexpr const int edtOffsetSecs = secsPerHour * edtOffsetHours;
    static constexpr const int cetOffsetSecs = secsPerHour * cetOffsetHours;

    QDateTime time( QDateTime::currentDateTimeUtc() );

    ui->mTimeLocal->setDateTime( time.toLocalTime() );

    ui->mTimeCDT->setDateTime( time.addSecs( cdtOffsetSecs ) );
    ui->mTimeEDT->setDateTime( time.addSecs( edtOffsetSecs ) );
    ui->mTimeCET->setDateTime( time.addSecs( cetOffsetSecs ) );
}
```

Comment: `constexpr` implies `const`.

Comment: `const int` is sufficient for every, but `constexpr int` might be more explicit. Please don't mix the two.

Comment: Isn't a const int created and destroyed each time the function is called, and therefore the calculations have to be made as well?  I know it can be optimized out, but I want to right it so the code says exactly what I'm implying.

Comment: @EddieV223 Those variables are `static` they are not created for every instance

Answer (score 7):

Your use is fine, if not a little verbose.  In this context `constexpr` and `const` mean exactly the same thing.  Either one (or even both) will do.

Fwiw, `std::chrono::hours::period::num` would be another way to specify `60*60` (if you want to show off some C++11 cred :-)).

Or actually you could just do:

```
void MainWindow::UpdateDateTimes()
{
    constexpr std::chrono::seconds cdtOffsetSecs = std::chrono::hours(-5);
    constexpr std::chrono::seconds edtOffsetSecs = std::chrono::hours(-4);
    constexpr std::chrono::seconds cetOffsetSecs = std::chrono::hours(2);

    QDateTime time( QDateTime::currentDateTimeUtc() );

    ui->mTimeLocal->setDateTime( time.toLocalTime() );

    ui->mTimeCDT->setDateTime( time.addSecs( cdtOffsetSecs.count() ) );
    ui->mTimeEDT->setDateTime( time.addSecs( edtOffsetSecs.count() ) );
    ui->mTimeCET->setDateTime( time.addSecs( cetOffsetSecs.count() ) );
}
```

Also I'd be tempted to drop the `static`.  On my system the exact same code gets generated with or without `static`.  It is all happening at compile time, so there's no need for the `static` "once only" initialization semantics.

**Update**

Just to make this crystal clear, I edited the original example to:

```
void f(int);

void UpdateDateTimes()
{
    constexpr std::chrono::seconds cdtOffsetSecs = std::chrono::hours(-5);
    constexpr std::chrono::seconds edtOffsetSecs = std::chrono::hours(-4);
    constexpr std::chrono::seconds cetOffsetSecs = std::chrono::hours(2);

    f(cdtOffsetSecs.count());
}
```

Compiled it with -O1 (optimizations barely enabled) with clang++ and libc++ and the assembly is:

```
    .globl  __Z15UpdateDateTimesv
    .align  4, 0x90
__Z15UpdateDateTimesv:                  ## @_Z15UpdateDateTimesv
    .cfi_startproc
## BB#0:
    pushq   %rbp
Ltmp2:
    .cfi_def_cfa_offset 16
Ltmp3:
    .cfi_offset %rbp, -16
    movq    %rsp, %rbp
Ltmp4:
    .cfi_def_cfa_register %rbp
    movl    $-18000, %edi           ## imm = 0xFFFFFFFFFFFFB9B0
    popq    %rbp
    jmp __Z1fi                  ## TAILCALL
    .cfi_endproc
```

I then compiled this program with the same settings:

```
void UpdateDateTimes2()
{
    f(-18000);
}
```

And the generated assembly is:

```
    .globl  __Z16UpdateDateTimes2v
    .align  4, 0x90
__Z16UpdateDateTimes2v:                 ## @_Z16UpdateDateTimes2v
    .cfi_startproc
## BB#0:
    pushq   %rbp
Ltmp7:
    .cfi_def_cfa_offset 16
Ltmp8:
    .cfi_offset %rbp, -16
    movq    %rsp, %rbp
Ltmp9:
    .cfi_def_cfa_register %rbp
    movl    $-18000, %edi           ## imm = 0xFFFFFFFFFFFFB9B0
    popq    %rbp
    jmp __Z1fi                  ## TAILCALL
    .cfi_endproc
```

So imho this is about as close as one ever gets to a [free lunch](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/TANSTAAFL). :-)